# Image size vs ration - how to work with images for hero banner, and image grids?

Tags: html, css, image

when it comes to working with images what is the approach on how to handle different sizes, aspect ratios, and resolutions?

Lets say I would like to create a grid with images where some of the images are square (2 columns) and few that are taking the full width of that grid. The Container with at the largest breakpoint has 1365px width. Gap horizontal and vertical between elements is 15px.

Based on that information do I need image that is specifically made for this dimension i.e 1365px / 12 - 7px or I can just use any image that is rectangular and set it to objectfit cover the div. Is display grid even the best choices for that use case?

Question is do I need those image in correct size and do I need to set any aspect rations on the div that is being covered with the image?

I can imagine there are few technique but witch approach would be best if I work with different partners where I need to provide them with required sizes and dimensions of those images? I would like the sizing to be consistent across the website.

Any help would be much appreciated.